# Can't set fast-connectable on my Bluetooth controller with BlueZ5

Tags: linux, bluetooth, linux-kernel, bluez

I can't set `fast-connectable` on my Bluetooth controller:

```
# btmgmt fast-conn on
Set Fast Connectable for hci0 failed with status 0x0c (Not Supported)
```

though `fast-connectable` is supported according to `btmgmt`!

```
# btmgmt info
Index list with 1 item
hci0:   Primary controller
    addr 4C:74:03:64:82:1F version 7 manufacturer 15 class 0x000000
    supported settings: powered connectable fast-connectable discoverable bondable link-security ssp br/edr hs le advertising secure-conn debug-keys privacy configuration static-addr 
    current settings: powered connectable bondable le secure-conn 
    name mybox
    short name 
hci0:   Configuration options
    supported options: public-address 
    missing options:
```

Same problem if the controller is powered off

```
# btmgmt power off
```

before trying to apply `fast-connectable`...

Would you have any idea why?

I'm running a Linux 4.1.20 kernel, with BlueZ 5.49.

I searched the Internet, the BlueZ documentation, but couldn't find much information about the setting `fast-connectable`. Help would be appreciated.

Comment: fast connectable is for br/edr. Your "supported settings" shows that your hardware supports br/edr. The other condition which returns "Not supported" error from kernel is if that HCI version should be above 2(core 1.2).

Comment: How do I check the HCI version? I have BlueZ 5.49 so HCI version should be 5, no?

Comment: `Bluetooth: Core ver 2.20` is displayed in my startup logs.

Comment: I have `class 0x000000` though the controller is `powered` and it looks like this is the cause. If I set the class to 0x400424 then I can set `fast-connectable`.

Comment: I have bluetooth 4.2 with bluez-5.48. I am able to set fast-connectable even with class 0x000000.

Comment: I have another device with bluetooth 2.1, bluez-5.48 and kernel 4.1.8. Able to set fast-connectable with/without class set.

Comment: Ok. Thanks for the information.